# Traduction arabe laravel

Tags: laravel, arabic

I'm working on a project with multiple languages. I have already installed French and English, now I need to add Arabic. 
I create a ar.json file with traduction and 
I added the arabic to config/app.php as
`'locales' => ['fr','en','ar',],`

Now, I just need to know how to add the rest of code in my view so that I can add the Arabic language with others

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownFlag" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Français">
            <img width="20" height="20" alt="{{ session('locale') }}"
                    src="{!! asset('images/flags/' . session('locale') . '-flag.png') !!}"/>
        </a>
        <div id="flags" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownFlag">
            @foreach(config('app.locales') as $locale)
                @if($locale != session('locale'))
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('language', $locale) }}" title="Anglais">
                        <img width="20" height="20" alt="{{ session('locale') }}"
                                src="{!! asset('images/flags/' . $locale . '-flag.png') !!}"/>
                    </a>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: check out this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#strings

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI just i need to edit my view by adding code to implement arabic language with the others

Comment: The foreach(config('app.locales') as $locale) loop is already iterate through your configured locales. What do you mean by " implement arabic language" ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI i have already installed the 2 languages Franch and English and are working, juste i need to add the arabic in my view, i have created a json file to traduce from franch to arabic.

Comment: @MedAliMhaya which strings you need to translate ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI i need to translate all the words in the site

Answer (score 0):

> You may retrieve lines from language files using the `__` helper
>   function. The `__` method accepts the file and key of the translation
>   string as its first argument. For example, let's retrieve the welcome
>   translation string from the resources/lang/messages.php language file:

```
echo __('file.key');
```

> If you are using the Blade templating engine, you may use the `{{ }}`
>   syntax to echo the translation string or use the `@lang` directive:

```
{{ __('file.key') }}

@lang('file.key')
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization)